# how to read file system programmatically

Tags: unix, hdfs

I have created a spreadsheet containing all the directory names & timestamps in a hadoop directory.  I manually copied each day's entries into my spreadsheet.  Now, management wants me to create a report from this data and have it auto-update.

My initial approach was to write a script which reads the file system into a text file, create a Hive table on that text file, and read the table contents into Tableau.  I realize Tableau can source text files, but only local to my laptop as far as I know.

Does this approach make sense?  Am I over-complicating this?
Can anyone provide a more streamlined solution?
Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need Tableau?  What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I need to be able to read the results of "hdfs dfs -ls /some/directory/path" into some structure which can be used by Tableau.  Tableau is our corporate B.I tool.

Comment: Hive definitely seems like overkill.  A script that processes the text then pushes to Tableau with it's APIs sounds like a better solution.  https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref.htm

Comment: OK, I will review the Tableau REST API information.  Thank you!